# Try to getting data from API using java

Tags: java

I'm a .Net guy. I tried to call API and getting data from.
Serialized JSON object using java.. but I'm getting this error.

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

In .NET it's really easy to do. but in java, I haven't idea how to do that.

this my model class

```
public class Dictionary {

@SerializedName("metadata")
@Expose
private Metadata metadata;
@SerializedName("results")
@Expose
private List<Result> results = null;

public Metadata getMetadata() {
return metadata;
}

public void setMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
this.metadata = metadata;
}

public List<Result> getResults() {
return results;
}

public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
this.results = results;
}

}
```

And here the my api call

```
public class Oxford {

    public String URL_OXFORD = "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/inflections/en/swimming";

    public static List<Dictionary> httpGet(String url, String function) {

    List<Dictionary> dataFromService = new ArrayList<Dictionary>();
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url+function);   
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("app_id", "566566");
        request.addHeader("app_key", "somekey");
        HttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);
        String json = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity(), "UTF-8");  

        com.google.gson.Gson gson = new com.google.gson.Gson();                       
        Dictionary[] response =  gson.fromJson(json, Dictionary[].class);

        System.out.println(response.length);   
        for(Dictionary file : response)
        {
            dataFromService.add(file);
             System.out.println(file.toString());
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    return dataFromService;
}
```

Comment: Your response is a json object starting with `{`, but you are reading in an array, try to print the json and generate POJO from the same (if required)

Comment: You omitted one of the important bits, the input JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the documentation returns one object (starting with {, not a [) you probably need a

```
Dictionary response
```

instead of

```
Dictionary[] response
```

Answer (score 1):

It is returning one dictionary object, not an array. Checkout the documentation at https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation